# For Loops turn to simple lines

Tags: python

If i know there will be three levels of json file, and I wanna match the third level of text. i can have code shown like below. But if i don't know exact number of levels, how can I write a generic function for this in python? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```py
values=['text1','text2','text3']
event_json={'text1':[{
               'othertext': {}, 
               'text2': [{
                     'text3':{.....}, 
                     'othertext1': {},
                     ....}], 
             ...}]}


def function():
            if event_json:
                for event in event_json['text1']:
                    for activity in event['text2']:
                        if 'text3' in activity and 
                           activity['text3'] == expected_name:
                            print('Match the text')
```

Comment: The keys to use are ALL in `values`  ?

Comment: Kind of. The items in values are like json path: text1.text2.text3 and by using each text to target specific key and loop inside to target the next level of the key

Comment: Do you always have the path in values array ?

Comment: For example, in the event_json file, I tried to find any key equals "text1", if I found it, i will get the value of this key and searching this value to see if I can find any key equals "text2", then keep doing the similar thing until I target to the last text in the "values" and do some match.

Comment: But firs level is a dict, then it's array, are your sure of this ?

Comment: yes. I can control always passing the path to the values

Comment: they are all dict at each level

Comment: Nope, value of text1 is an array, same then

Comment: the event_json is actually service log. So they are dict.

Comment: oh. I wanna define values as string list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may iterate over the `values` of the path you have then depending the current value if a `dict` or `list` you check into

```
values = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
event_json = {'text1': [{'text2': [{'text3': "LOOKFOR"}], }]}

def function(expected):
    value = event_json
    for key in values:
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if key not in value:
                print(value, key)
                return -1
            value = value[key]

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for obj in value:
                if key in obj:
                    value = obj[key]
                    break
            else:
                return -2
    return value == expected # if it's array change to : expected in value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(function("LOOKFOR"))  # true
    print(function("LOOK-FOR")) # false
```

Comment: Thank, let me try it.